# Dramatic timing differences between code compiled for linux 3.2.x vs 2.6.x based systems

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel, porting, glibc

I have an application that was written, tested, and debugged for a small linux distribution with a version 2.6.x kernel. I recently attempted to migrate the project to a distribution based on Debian with a 3.2.x kernel and we note huge performance decreases.  I've done some primitive benchmarking and found differences in usleep() timing, differences in function call & loop timing, etc.

I'm not sure what the exact 2.6.x kernel configuration is (e.g. preemption model, etc) and I haven't been able to extract kernel build configuration info - we just have this system as an image that we've been using for our embedded applications.  For the 3.2.x kernel I built a configuration with optimizations for our processor, with a "preemptable kernel" configuration, and removed a bunch of utterly unneeded optional modules (stuff like HAM radio device drivers - stuff that stuck out as totally reasonable to remove).

Our system is a near-realtime application that doesn't have hard realtime requirements (we just have to keep certain buffers populated with computed data before it gets consumed, which *is* done at a fixed rate, but one controlled by hardware and in practice our CPU load stays around 30% for the most demanding applications -ie, we have the performance to keep the buffer populated and do a fair bit of waiting for space).  We use pthreads, pthread_cond_wait/broadcast, etc, to signal buffer states, control thread synchronization, etc.

First, some preamble about the system. There are many polling threads with the pattern:

```
while (threadRunning)
{
   CheckSomeStuff();
   usleep(polling_interval);
}
```

And other threads with patterns like:

```
while (threadRunning) 
{
    pthread_cond_wait(stuff_needed_condition, some_mutex); // wait on signal
    doSomeStuffWhenNeeded();
}
```

That said, we are noticing subtle timing-related issues in the ported application, and algorithms are running a lot "slower" than on the 2.6.x kernel based system.

This simple benchmark is illustrative:

```
static volatile long g_foo;

static void setfoo(long foo)
{
    g_foo = foo;
}

static void printElapsed(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2, const char* smsg)
{
    double time_elapsed;
    time_elapsed = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1e6 + (t2.tv_usec-t1.tv_usec);
    printf("%s elapsed:  %.8f\n", smsg, time_elapsed);
}

static void benchmarks(long sleeptime)
{
    long i;

    double time_elapsed;

    struct timeval t1, t2;

    // test 1
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    for (i=0;i<sleeptime;i++)
    {
       usleep(1);
    }
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    printElapsed(t1, t2, "Loop usleep(1)");

    // test 2
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    usleep(sleeptime);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    printElapsed(t1, t2, "Single sleep");


    // test 3
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    usleep(1);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    printElapsed(t1, t2, "Single 1us sleep");

    // test 4
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    printElapsed(t1, t2, "gettimeofday x 2");

    // test 5
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        setfoo(i);
    }
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    printElapsed(t1, t2, "loop function call");
}
```

Here are the benchmark results (yeah, output decimal places is silly I know):

```
Kernel 2.6.x trial 1:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  6063979.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100071.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  63.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  1.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  267.00000000

Kernel 2.6.x trial 2:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  6059328.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100070.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  63.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  0.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  265.00000000

Kernel 2.6.x trial 3:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  6063762.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100064.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  63.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  1.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  266.00000000


kernel 3.2.65 trial 1:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  8944631.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100106.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  96.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  2.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  491.00000000

kernel 3.2.65 trial 2:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  8891191.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100102.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  94.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  2.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  396.00000000

kernel 3.2.65 trial 3:
Loop usleep(1) elapsed:  8962089.00000000
Single sleep elapsed:  100171.00000000
Single 1us sleep elapsed:  123.00000000
gettimeofday x 2 elapsed:  2.00000000
loop function call elapsed:  407.00000000
```

There is a huge difference in walltime between builds on a linux OS using kernel 2.6.x and kernel 3.2.x for 100,000 cycles of a loop that calls usleep(1) (9 seconds for the 3.2.x vs 6 seconds for the 2.6.x).  For the record, I don't think we're using calls to "usleep(1);" anywhere in the code base (but as with any huge application worse things probably exist here and there) but nevertheless this is a big difference in behaviour. There are also big differences in the loop that sets a static global variable 100,000 times (400 microseconds on 3.2 vs 260 microseconds on 2.6).

I realize there are multiple confounding issues from glibc to compiler & settings to the linux kernel configuration.  What I'm hoping from Stack Overflow is to get some guidance in terms of where to start poking.  What would *you* do if you had to accomplish this migration?  What factors would you look at to fix the performance issues we're seeing?

For further info, the two distributions are:

Puppy Linux 
- kernel 2.6.35-7 SMP unknown kernel configuration (PREEMPT though, I'm pretty sure)
- glibc 2.6.1
- gcc 4.6.3

Debian wheezy 7.7 (stripped down)
- Linux 3.2.65 custom config from kernel sources
- gcc 4.7.2
- glibc 2.13 (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u6)

Comment: Firstly, you need to describe how you came to the conclusion that "algorithms are running a lot slower". That's critical information for someone to have any chance of deciding where to look next. Secondly, it's not clear why you are testing usleep. That may or may not have any bearing on your problem. That's almost a microbenchmark. Your problems sound more system wide and thus IMHO you should start at a more broader system level and not zoom down immediately to such a micro level. Once you provide more info on what "slow" means in your case perhaps someone can give better suggestions.

Comment: On the "microbenchmarking" level, you'll see on the 2.6.x system a 100,000 iterations loop takes ~250 milliseconds whereas on the 3.2.x system it takes around 400 milliseconds (single threaded process, idle system, running at highest priority nicelevel).  

On a macro level, we're seeing computations involving floating point computations taking more walltime.  Thread scheduling is one reasonably likely culprit here, but even for single threaded test processes we're seeing the same computation requiring more  wall clock time.

Answer (score 0):

You've updated the kernel, compiler and glibc versions.

Don't do *that*. Update *one* thing at a time, and measure the effects. Then you'll know which of the updates is actually causing your problems (it's likely not the kernel).

You should be able to update just the kernel, then just the glibc on the old system.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion.  I'll see about approaching this in a more diagnostic way.